# How to insert or create a visual separation between groups of bars within ggplot2 in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-col

I would like to create a separation between the groups (D, E, F, G, H, I e J) of slashes inside ggplot.

Using the diamonds database.

```
ggplot(diamonds, aes(x = color, y=depth, fill=factor(clarity ))) +
  geom_col(position = "dodge")+
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("red4", "seagreen3", "grey", "yellow", "black", "blue", "green", "sienna","tomato1", "tan2"), name="clarity") +
  theme_light()
```

I've:

[image]

but I would like to create some visual separation between the groups in a simple way, similar to this`

[image]

OBS1: `facet_grid` won't work because I'm going to use two other variables to add to `facet_grid`.

OBS2: For clarification: I'd like to add something visual that helps visually separate the groups, to make it easier to understand where each group starts and ends.

OB3:I edited the second image (Expectative) with rectangles separating each group. The idea would be more or less this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT: new answer - use `geom_rect`.**

```
ggplot(diamonds, 
       aes(x = color, 
           y = depth, 
           fill = factor(clarity ))) +
    geom_col(position = "dodge") +
    geom_rect(aes(xmin = as.numeric(color) - 0.5, 
                  xmax = as.numeric(color) + 0.5), 
              ymin = -0.5, 
              ymax = Inf, 
              color = "red", 
              fill = NA, 
              size = 2) +
    scale_fill_manual(values = c("red4", "seagreen3", "grey", "yellow", "black",
                                 "blue", "green", "sienna","tomato1", "tan2"), 
                      name = "clarity") + 
    theme_light()
```

Result:

[image]

**OLD ANSWER - before you modified your question.**

I think the easiest way is to use `facet_grid`. It's not really designed for that purpose, but will result in the required visual effect.

```
ggplot(diamonds, 
       aes(x = color, 
           y = depth, 
           fill = factor(clarity ))) +
geom_col(position = "dodge") +
scale_fill_manual(values = c("red4", "seagreen3", "grey", "yellow", "black",
                             "blue", "green", "sienna","tomato1", "tan2"), 
                             name = "clarity") + 
facet_grid(. ~ color, 
           scales = "free_x", 
           switch = "x") + 
theme_light() + 
theme(axis.text.x = element_blank(), 
      axis.ticks.x = element_blank())
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But facet_grid won't work because I'm going to use two other variables to add to facet_grid

Comment: In that case can you use more realistic example data, code and desired output in your question.

Comment: Answer edited with a new solution.

Comment: that was exactly what I was needing. I would like to understand why it was necessary to convert the qualitative variable `color` to a number system as shown in `(xmin = as.numeric(color) - 0.5, xmax = as.numeric(color) + 0.5)`?

Comment: The x-axis has an underlying numeric scale even though the variable is categorical. Each group of bars is centered with 0.5 of the width each side. So conversion to numeric and adding/subtracting 0.5 places the vertical side of the rectangle in the right position. Please consider voting for and/or accepting the answer if it solves the issue.

Answer (score 2):

using `geom_vline`

```
ggplot(diamonds, aes(x = color, y=depth, fill=factor(clarity ))) +
  geom_col(position = "dodge")+
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("red4", "seagreen3", "grey", "yellow", "black", "blue", "green", "sienna","tomato1", "tan2"), name="clarity") +
  theme_light() +
  geom_vline(xintercept = (0:7)+0.5)
```

[image]

Comment: unbelievable, that's how it was. Additionally, would it be possible to change the color to red and use a dotted line?

Answer (score 1):

The `geom_vline()` method already posted in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70675991/9664796) will answer your specific request quite well; however, it's probably not the best solution to your problem *graphically*.  Even with lines drawn between the bars... it's super difficult to separate visually the sets of bars from one another.  The bars are already thin, so drawing a thin vertical line is going to make it very difficult for the viewer to separate the line from the bar.  If you plan to facet your data in addition to this, the issue will get even worse.

The alternative I would propose is to use whitespace to separate your groups of bars by utilizing `position=position_dodge(width=...)` and the `width=...` argument inside of `geom_col()` itself.  Here's examples of what this does from your posted example.

#### Using width inside of geom_col()

```
ggplot(diamonds, aes(x = color, y=depth, fill=factor(clarity ))) +
  geom_col(position = "dodge", width=0.5)+
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("red4", "seagreen3", "grey", "yellow", "black", "blue", "green", "sienna","tomato1", "tan2"), name="clarity") +
  theme_light()
```

[image]

You can see that the argument for `width=` in `geom_col()` has the effect to change the width of the overall geom in each x position.  Thus this value controls the width of the *entire group* of bars.  This small change is enough to clearly show the separation without adding lines (and maintaining a bit of whitespace to make things easier to compare).

*(For comparison, the default `width=` is something like 0.7 or 0.8).*

#### Using position_dodge(width=...) to control group spacing

You may want to adjust just a bit further the graph above to provide a tiny bit of separation between the bars.  This one is a bit more on visual preference, but is useful to know as a tool to control the position of groups of bars.  `position="dodge"` is a shorthand way of saying `position=position_dodge()`.  The default width puts the bars right next to each other, wherein the `width=` argument inside `position_dodge()` is equal to the `width=` of the overall geom.  If you make this number larger in `position_dodge()`, you'll add spacing between the bars.  If you make it smaller, you will get overlapping bars.  Here's what happens when you add just a bit of spacing between the bars:

```
ggplot(diamonds, aes(x = color, y=depth, fill=factor(clarity ))) +
  geom_col(position = position_dodge(width=0.6), width=0.5)+
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("red4", "seagreen3", "grey", "yellow", "black", "blue", "green", "sienna","tomato1", "tan2"), name="clarity") +
  theme_light()
```

[image]

I think it looks a bit better than having the bars next to each other, but it will depend on your own specific chart and how many facets, x position values, and bars in each group you have.